# двоякое представление байтов

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Имеется код:

```
unsigned char buffer;
FILE *fp = fopen("1.jpg", "rb");
char *buf_arr;
int i = 0, k = 0;

buf_arr = (char*)malloc((20 + 1) * sizeof(char));
memset(buf_arr, 0 , (20 + 1) * sizeof(char));

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    fread(&buffer, 1, 1, fp);
    buf_arr[k] = buffer;
    k++;
}
```

странность заключается в том, что когда файл читается один байт за другим, то при выводе их на консоль байты отображаются корректно. А вот если `fread` прочитать сразу 20 байт в `buf_arr`, то после 10-ого байта появятся некорректные байты (десятичные числа со знаком минус). Мне нужно записать данные в массив, но как я могу их записывать, если они некорректные? Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

P.S. если выводить побайтово - 80 75 3 4 20 0 0 0 8 0 34 99 150 74 205 98 214
 если считать сразу в массив - 80 75 3 4 20 0 0 0 0 0 34 99 -106 74 -51 98 -42

Answer (score 4):

Ну вот давайте глянем представление 150 в бинарном виде - это 10010110. Если трактовать это как **знаковое** значение, получим ваше -106.

Т.е. это просто трактовка `char` как знакового значения. Пользуйтесь `unsigned char` и все будет в порядке...

Comment: елки - палки, спасибо :) я переменную `buffer` unsigned сделал, а почему-то массив - нет.